# Providing an ad-hoc report facility for business using in MySQL and PHP?

Tags: mysql

We are using MySQL 5.2 CE. We need to provide the business users a way to create their own ad-hoc report.

Could you give a suggestion and an example, if this can de done using PHP?

Answer (score 3):

I suppose you could wire up some gnarly PHP code that queries `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` for database objects and then presents them to your end-users using some glamorous jquery and HTML5 elements. Then you'd have to generate SQL from the user's input.

Or, you could go through a bit of effort to implement/deploy [BIRT](http://www.eclipse.org/birt/phoenix/) to your user base.

However, my *personal preference* for doing ad-hoc querying would probably be Pentaho. There's still the overhead of deploying this to your users, but I find their documentation and implementation to be straightforward and easy-to-follow. [Here's a link to using Ad-Hoc reporting](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/ServerDoc1x/Creating+Reports+using+Adhoc+Reporting) in the Pentaho suite.